# Kernel Development with Raspberry Pi

Tags: pi-2, linux, kernel

I want to start working and playing with linux kernel. Instead of trying on my own system, I want to do the same on raspberry pi. 
I want to compile my own kernel and start working on my first kernel patch.

I'm a beginner at kernel development, so want to try it out on direct hardware rather than VM.

The building kernel on raspberry is different from that of the normal hardware? As the process of configuring the kernel and making it is different [in the provided link](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/kernel/building.md). So is it advisable using raspberry pi or use normal system for a complete newbie?

Comment: Yes, try it. But what is the question?

Comment: I thought to compile on rasberry pi is a better choice rather than on my working machine.

But I started doing it on my own machine rather than rasberry pi.

Comment: Yes, you will do that. But this site has a question and answer format so you should ask a question, the sentence with a question mark at the end, something like this: "where is the question?"

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps look at https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/kernel/building.md

Kernel patching/building requires self learning including the ability to use a web search and interpret the results.

Comment: The building kernel on raspberry is different from that of the normal hardware ? As the process of configuring the kernel and making it is different in the provided link.
So is it advisable using raspberry pi or use normal system for a complete newbie ?